# showDialog from Future method flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dialog

I have Button and I want to call a method to check a case, if the case is true, then I do some code, else I want to show a dialog.

The code for the UI:

```
new RaisedButton(key:null, onPressed:buttonPressed,
                color: const Color(0xFFe0e0e0),
                child:
                new Text(
                  "Submit",
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize:12.0,
                      color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      fontFamily: "Roboto"),
                )
            )
```

The method is:

```
Future<void> buttonPressed() async {
if (DataStore.shared.getPerson() != null)
  {
    // do some code...
  }
else
  {
    // show dialog 
        await showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Login'),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ListBody(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Login is required to submit.'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Login'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/login");
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
  }
}
```

The Dialog is not shown.

Comment: did you check it is entering in else part by printing anything ? Because this code is working fine when i tried.

Comment: Yes I did. Nothing is appearing